# Launching graphical application from tty to improve performance

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, tty

Would there be any performance increase by opening a tty terminal and

```
exec application
```

as opposed to launching from a DE/WM, or would that only be the case if I were to boot without starting xorg (if at all)?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: If it's a graphical application, you're going to need at the very least Xorg running; depending on which application, possibly even more.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have Xorg running, it uses memory and CPU-time.  There's one computer to share among all of the processes.  If you omit the Xorg processes, there's more available resources for your application.

Comment: Note that this ONLY applies if the process you're trying to run isn't a graphic one.

Comment: OP's "opening a tty terminal" made it clear that it is not.

Comment: Not necessarily. I start roughly two thirds of my graphical applications from command line in an xterm.

Comment: Most people equate "tty terminal" on Linux with its virtual consoles (your experience may differ).

Comment: I should clarify. The "Starting applications without a window manager" section of [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc#Autostart_X_at_login) mentions starting an application without running "startx". I was wondering if opening a terminal from a WM/DE with
ctrl + alt + F1 would have the same benefits.

Comment: You are describing the way to open a Linux virtual console.  In that case, the WM/DE continue to run, using memory and CPU time.